# Hibernate retorna muitas consultas e sobrescreve minhas alterações

Tags: java, hibernate

Boa tarde pessoal, estou tentando realizar uma alteração em um datatable, ao clicar no rowEditor, o valor é enviado corretamente, porem, não sei porque, está sendo realizada muitas consultas com o hibernate.
Não sei se consegui me explicar direito, mas estou postando o código e a saída com as explicações.... 
agradeço muito :)

listaProduto.xhtml

```
            <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 

    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">



    <ui:composition template= "template.xhtml">

    <ui:define name="conteudo" >

    <h:form id="form">



                <p:growl id="msgs" showDetail="true"/>

    <p:dataTable  var="prod" value="#{pBean.listaproduto}" editable="true" style="margin-bottom:20px" id="listaproduto" >


            <p:ajax event="rowEdit" listener="#{pBean.onRowEdit}" update=":form:listaproduto" />


        <p:column headerText="ID">
            <p:cellEditor>
                <f:facet name="output"><h:outputText value="#{prod.nome}"/></f:facet>
                <f:facet name="input"><p:inputText id="idProd" value="#{prod.id}" style="width:100%"/></f:facet>
            </p:cellEditor>
        </p:column>

        <p:column headerText="Nome">
            <p:cellEditor>
                <f:facet name="output"><h:outputText value="#{prod.nome}"/></f:facet>
                <f:facet name="input"><p:inputText id="idNome" value="#{prod.nome}" style="width:100%"/></f:facet>
            </p:cellEditor>
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="Preço">
            <p:cellEditor>
                <f:facet name="output"><h:outputText value="#{prod.preco}"/></f:facet>
                <f:facet name="input"><p:inputText id="idPreco" value="#{prod.preco}" style="width:100%"/></f:facet>
            </p:cellEditor>
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="Fornecedor">
            <p:cellEditor>
                <f:facet name="output"><h:outputText value="#{prod.fornecedor}"/></f:facet>
                <f:facet name="input"><p:inputText id="idFornecedor" value="#{prod.fornecedor}" style="width:100%"/></f:facet>
            </p:cellEditor>
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="Categoria">
      <p:cellEditor>
          <f:facet name="output"><h:outputText value="#{prod.categoria}"/></f:facet>
          <f:facet name="input"><p:inputText  id="idCategoria" value="#{prod.categoria}" style="width:100%"/></f:facet>
      </p:cellEditor>
</p:column>             



    <p:column style="width:32px">
        <p:rowEditor  />


    </p:column> 
</p:dataTable>

    </h:form>



</ui:define>

</ui:composition>

</html>
```

pBean

```
public List<Produto> getListaproduto() {
            try{

            System.out.println( "get " + listaproduto);

                listaproduto = new ProdutoDao().listar();



            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            return listaproduto;
        }


        public void onRowEdit(RowEditEvent event) {

     System.out.println( "no onRowEdit " + listaproduto);


        }
```

ProdutoDao

```
        public List<Produto> listar()throws Exception {
        session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        query = session.createQuery("select p from Produto p");

        List<Produto> lista = query.list();
        session.close();

            return lista;
        }
```

Retorno do Console ao clicar no v do rowEditor (repare que antes do 4º select de baixo pra cima, o System.out.println( "get " + listaproduto), retorna o valor correto que passei....)

```
        get null
    Hibernate: 
        select
            this_.id as id1_0_0_,
            this_.categoria as categori2_0_0_,
            this_.fornecedor as forneced3_0_0_,
            this_.nome as nome4_0_0_,
            this_.preco as preco5_0_0_ 
        from
            Produto this_
    get [Produto [id= 1, nome= tetse, preco= 534534.0, fornecedor= teste, categoria= teste], Produto [id= 2, nome= 123, preco= 123.0, fornecedor= 123, categoria= 123]]
    Hibernate: 
        select
            this_.id as id1_0_0_,
            this_.categoria as categori2_0_0_,
            this_.fornecedor as forneced3_0_0_,
            this_.nome as nome4_0_0_,
            this_.preco as preco5_0_0_ 
        from
            Produto this_
    get [Produto [id= 1, nome= tetse, preco= 534534.0, fornecedor= teste, categoria= teste], Produto [id= 2, nome= 123, preco= 123.0, fornecedor= 123, categoria= 123]]
    Hibernate: 
        select
            this_.id as id1_0_0_,
            this_.categoria as categori2_0_0_,
            this_.fornecedor as forneced3_0_0_,
            this_.nome as nome4_0_0_,
            this_.preco as preco5_0_0_ 
        from
            Produto this_
    get [Produto [id= 1, nome= tetse, preco= 534534.0, fornecedor= teste, categoria= teste], Produto [id= 2, nome= 123, preco= 123.0, fornecedor= 123, categoria= 123]]
    Hibernate: 
        select
            this_.id as id1_0_0_,
            this_.categoria as categori2_0_0_,
            this_.fornecedor as forneced3_0_0_,
            this_.nome as nome4_0_0_,
            this_.preco as preco5_0_0_ 
        from
            Produto this_
    get [Produto [id= 1, nome= tetse, preco= 534534.0, fornecedor= teste, categoria= teste], Produto [id= 2, nome= 123, preco= 123.0, fornecedor= 123, categoria= 123]]
    Hibernate: 
        select
            this_.id as id1_0_0_,
            this_.categoria as categori2_0_0_,
            this_.fornecedor as forneced3_0_0_,
            this_.nome as nome4_0_0_,
            this_.preco as preco5_0_0_ 
        from
            Produto this_
    get [Produto [id= 1, nome= tetse, preco= 534534.0, fornecedor= teste, categoria= teste], Produto [id= 2, nome= 123, preco= 123.0, fornecedor= 123, categoria= 123]]
    Hibernate: 
        select
            this_.id as id1_0_0_,
            this_.categoria as categori2_0_0_,
            this_.fornecedor as forneced3_0_0_,
            this_.nome as nome4_0_0_,
            this_.preco as preco5_0_0_ 
        from
            Produto this_
    get [Produto [id= 1, nome= tetse, preco= 534534.0, fornecedor= teste, categoria= teste], Produto [id= 2, nome= 123, preco= 123.0, fornecedor= 123, categoria= 123]]
    Hibernate: 
        select
            this_.id as id1_0_0_,
            this_.categoria as categori2_0_0_,
            this_.fornecedor as forneced3_0_0_,
            this_.nome as nome4_0_0_,
            this_.preco as preco5_0_0_ 
        from
            Produto this_
    get [Produto [id= 1, nome= tetse, preco= 534534.0, fornecedor= teste, categoria= teste], Produto [id= 2, nome= 123, preco= 123.0, fornecedor= 123, categoria= 123]]
    Hibernate: 
        select
            this_.id as id1_0_0_,
            this_.categoria as categori2_0_0_,
            this_.fornecedor as forneced3_0_0_,
            this_.nome as nome4_0_0_,
            this_.preco as preco5_0_0_ 
        from
            Produto this_
    get [Produto [id= 1, nome= tetse, preco= 534534.0, fornecedor= teste, categoria= teste], Produto [id= 2, nome= 123, preco= 123.0, fornecedor= 123, categoria= 123]]
    Hibernate: 
        select
            this_.id as id1_0_0_,
            this_.categoria as categori2_0_0_,
            this_.fornecedor as forneced3_0_0_,
            this_.nome as nome4_0_0_,
            this_.preco as preco5_0_0_ 
        from
            Produto this_
    get [Produto [id= 1, nome= tetse, preco= 534534.0, fornecedor= teste, categoria= teste], Produto [id= 2, nome= 123, preco= 123.0, fornecedor= 123, categoria= 123]]
    Hibernate: 
        select
            this_.id as id1_0_0_,
            this_.categoria as categori2_0_0_,
            this_.fornecedor as forneced3_0_0_,
            this_.nome as nome4_0_0_,
            this_.preco as preco5_0_0_ 
        from
            Produto this_
    get [Produto [id= 1, nome= tetse, preco= 534534.0, fornecedor= teste, categoria= teste], Produto [id= 2, nome= 123, preco= 123.0, fornecedor= 123, categoria= 123]]
    Hibernate: 
        select
            this_.id as id1_0_0_,
            this_.categoria as categori2_0_0_,
            this_.fornecedor as forneced3_0_0_,
            this_.nome as nome4_0_0_,
            this_.preco as preco5_0_0_ 
        from
            Produto this_
    get [Produto [id= 1, nome= tetse, preco= 534534.0, fornecedor= teste, categoria= teste], Produto [id= 2, nome= 123, preco= 123.0, fornecedor= 123, categoria= 123]]
    Hibernate: 
        select
            this_.id as id1_0_0_,
            this_.categoria as categori2_0_0_,
            this_.fornecedor as forneced3_0_0_,
            this_.nome as nome4_0_0_,
            this_.preco as preco5_0_0_ 
        from
            Produto this_
    get [Produto [id= 1, nome= tetse, preco= 534534.0, fornecedor= teste, categoria= teste], Produto [id= 2, nome= 123, preco= 123.0, fornecedor= 123, categoria= 123]]
    Hibernate: 
        select
            this_.id as id1_0_0_,
            this_.categoria as categori2_0_0_,
            this_.fornecedor as forneced3_0_0_,
            this_.nome as nome4_0_0_,
            this_.preco as preco5_0_0_ 
        from
            Produto this_
    get [Produto [id= 1, nome= tetse, preco= 534534.0, fornecedor= teste, categoria= teste], Produto [id= 2, nome= 123, preco= 123.0, fornecedor= 123, categoria= 123]]
    Hibernate: 
        select
            this_.id as id1_0_0_,
            this_.categoria as categori2_0_0_,
            this_.fornecedor as forneced3_0_0_,
            this_.nome as nome4_0_0_,
            this_.preco as preco5_0_0_ 
        from
            Produto this_
    get [Produto [id= 1, nome= tetse, preco= 534534.0, fornecedor= teste, categoria= teste], Produto [id= 2, nome= 123, preco= 123.0, fornecedor= 123, categoria= 123]]
    Hibernate: 
        select
            this_.id as id1_0_0_,
            this_.categoria as categori2_0_0_,
            this_.fornecedor as forneced3_0_0_,
            this_.nome as nome4_0_0_,
            this_.preco as preco5_0_0_ 
        from
            Produto this_
    get [Produto [id= 1, nome= tetse, preco= 534534.0, fornecedor= teste, categoria= teste], Produto [id= 2, nome= 123, preco= 123.0, fornecedor= 123, categoria= 258]]
    Hibernate: 
        select
            this_.id as id1_0_0_,
            this_.categoria as categori2_0_0_,
            this_.fornecedor as forneced3_0_0_,
            this_.nome as nome4_0_0_,
            this_.preco as preco5_0_0_ 
        from
            Produto this_
    get [Produto [id= 1, nome= tetse, preco= 534534.0, fornecedor= teste, categoria= teste], Produto [id= 2, nome= 123, preco= 123.0, fornecedor= 123, categoria= 123]]
    Hibernate: 
        select
            this_.id as id1_0_0_,
            this_.categoria as categori2_0_0_,
            this_.fornecedor as forneced3_0_0_,
            this_.nome as nome4_0_0_,
            this_.preco as preco5_0_0_ 
        from
            Produto this_
    no onRowEdit [Produto [id= 1, nome= tetse, preco= 534534.0, fornecedor= teste, categoria= teste], Produto [id= 2, nome= 123, preco= 123.0, fornecedor= 123, categoria= 123]]
    get [Produto [id= 1, nome= tetse, preco= 534534.0, fornecedor= teste, categoria= teste], Produto [id= 2, nome= 123, preco= 123.0, fornecedor= 123, categoria= 123]]
    Hibernate: 
        select
            this_.id as id1_0_0_,
            this_.categoria as categori2_0_0_,
            this_.fornecedor as forneced3_0_0_,
            this_.nome as nome4_0_0_,
            this_.preco as preco5_0_0_ 
        from
            Produto this_
    get [Produto [id= 1, nome= tetse, preco= 534534.0, fornecedor= teste, categoria= teste], Produto [id= 2, nome= 123, preco= 123.0, fornecedor= 123, categoria= 123]]
    Hibernate: 
        select
            this_.id as id1_0_0_,
            this_.categoria as categori2_0_0_,
            this_.fornecedor as forneced3_0_0_,
            this_.nome as nome4_0_0_,
            this_.preco as preco5_0_0_ 
        from
            Produto this_
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amigo,

Seria bom se você postasse os dados de mapeamento da entidade Produto.

Para o primeiro problema, com relação a sobrescrever dados sugiro que você leia mais sobre a anotação @Cascade, propriedade utilizada  com mappedBy. Essa propriedade é responsável por propagar as modificações, talvez seu projeto esteja com CascadeType.ALL por isso está propagando as modificações. Há 5 tipos principais que você pode utilizar:

1. **NONE:** Não faz nada com o objeto (padrão)
2. **MERGE:** Faz update nos filhos quando faz update no pai
3. **PERSIST:** Salva o filho quando salva o pai
4. **REFRESH:** Salva o pai e mantem o filho sem alterar
5. **REMOVE:** Remove o filho quando remove o pai ou ao contrário
6. **ALL:** Propaga todas as alterações

Exemplos:

```
 @ManyToMany(cascade=CascadeType.MERGE) // anotação direta na ligação
 @Cascade(cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST}) //anotação individual
 @Cascade(cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST,CascadeType.REFRESH}) //anotação com combinações
```

No seu caso talvez `@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST)` resolva.

---

Com relação ao segundo problema (tazer muitos dados) você deverá estudar mais sobre FETCH. Por padrão quando o relacionamento está anotado com @OneToMany ou @ManyToMany ele é carregado de modo Lazy, ou seja, seu filhos não são carregados (Ex: Traz lista de produtos sem itens). Se você utilizar explicitamente @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER) todos os campos da tabela correpondente serão trazido.

No seu caso talvez `@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)` resolva.

Mais informações:

- http://www.devmedia.com.br/lazy-e-eager-loading-com-hibernate/29554
- http://blog.caelum.com.br/entendendo-o-lazy-e-o-eager-load-da-jpa/

Comment: Obrigado, mas meu problema estava no get do pBean, eu não especificava que quando listaproduto estivesse diferente de nulo, não tentasse realizar o preenchimento da lista. :)